# Format The NSNumber in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How can I convert NSNumber "1234567 " to "12,34,567"?

I have used the NSNumberFormatter for this,but couldn't get the desired result.

I am doing like this

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSString *formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1234567]];
    NSLog(@":%@",formattedString);
```

**Output**: 1,234,567

**Desired Output**: 12,34,567

Comment: What is your desired result.?

Comment: Show what you have tried. That way someone may be able to explain where you have gone wrong rather than you just being given an answer/code

Comment: You should read this first: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i have update my code. please anyone give me suggestion.

Comment: @maddycoder, what about iffi's code? did u try that?

Comment: @Aadhira:can you tell me what's the meaning of [numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"##,##,###"]; this line?

Comment: If your number is positive, then use `setPositiveFormat:`, and `#`s are used to format the number. [More info](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW9)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"##,##,###"];      
NSString *formattedNumberString = [numberFormatter 
      stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1234567]];
NSLog(@"formattedNumberString: %@", formattedNumberString);
[numberFormatter release];
```

Comment: You're welcome :) You can find more info on the subject in the apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW2 http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Number_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 3):

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1234567];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:number]);
[formatter release];
```

Comment: Will it give the output "12,34,567" or "1,234,567"?

Comment: it will give the output "1,234,567" not the result what i want which is "12,34,567".